# Adding Throttle suite in asp.net web service application

Tags: c#, web-services

While  sending too many request in one second, like 20 or 30 request which is causing our servers to slow down.while searching it shows throttling to solve the problem.

How can I add `throttle suite` in asp.net web service application?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it by simply typing "Install-Package ThrottlingSuite.Http" in package manager console.
For more info of how to configure it check http://throttlewebapi.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: actually,i am using visual studio 2010 at .net frame work 3.5,for installing this package"Install-Package ThrottlingSuite.Http", i need to change my frame work 4.5.but in .net 4.5 framework the  asp.net web service application is not working..

Comment: Than there is no way : ThrottlingSuite System Requirements are .NET 4.5 and vs2012 +

Comment: even in vs2012,i create a new project with .net4.5 it doesn't show  "asp.net web service application".is there is any other way to add throttling in  my web service .

Comment: whether i want to convert my web service into mvc application